# Specify dependency of my LLVM pass on the mem2reg pass

Tags: llvm, llvm-3.0

I am writing a `ModulePass` and invoke it using `opt -load`.  I would require that `alloca` has been promoted to registers when my pass runs, using the -mem2reg switch for opt.

There is a [link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.llvm.devel/35640) which indicates that the PromoteMemoryToRegsiter pass is a transform pass and as such should not be required by my pass.  That's a statement from 2010.  Does that still hold?

One of the posts I found suggested something like

```
AU.addRequiredID(PromoteMemoryToRegister::MemoryToRegisterID);
```

but that contradicted the post I linked above.

So my question is, how to I express this dependency for my pass, if possible?  How do I express, in general, such pass dependencies?  And what's the difference between a transform pass and, well, another pass?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What's the difference between a transform pass and another pass?

A transform pass is a pass that may invalidate the results of other passes.

> How to I express this dependency for my pass?

First of all, I recommend reading [the pass-dependency section of the official "how to write a pass" guide](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#id38). In any case, the correct way to add a dependency between transformation passes is to add one before the other in your pass manager ([see the guide section on the pass manager](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#writing-an-llvm-pass-passmanager)), or, if you just invoke `opt`, then add all the passes you want *in the order you want them to occur*, e.g.:

```
opt -load mypass.so -mem2reg -mypass
```

Comment: We're going forth and back between using `opt` and writing our own instance that uses a `PassManager`, not sure yet.  If the order is that easy to achieve, then that's good enough for now :)